# regex help - check few parts if they appear or not

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to check a URL which must consist of a few parts, but others are not mandatory.
Only if all parts are there according to the requirements, then this should be a match.

here's an example of a link, and after that i will explain what is mandatory and what is not:
https://www.example.com/truma.aspx?lang=en&project=31&utm_source=xxx&utm_medium=yyy

the first part is mandatory: 
https://www.example.com/truma.aspx?lang=en

the second part (project) is not mandatory, but if it exists, it could include only specific numbers (could be only 31, 32 or 33. any other number is not good):

&project=31

the last part (the utms) is optional - could be there and it is possible that they won't.

&utm_source=xxx&utm_medium=yyy
i don't mind having any other parameter (starting with &).

without the utm, i got to the following:
.*/truma.aspx?lang=en(&project=(31|32|33))?$

but when i tried to add the optional utms part - things fell apart for me.
once i got this running, i would like to see the option to have different order of parameters, but for now i want it to work in this order i mentioned in the beginning.

thanks!

Comment: *"things fell apart for me"* doesn't tell us a lot. What do you mean? One thing: `aspx?` is a flaw in this. Should be `apsx\?` because otherwise the x would be optional. But you want an actual `?` to be found.

Comment: you are right about the \?

as for the fell apart - what i meant i just tried many things and couldn't get it working...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following pattern gives you an idea... it does not cover everything but it might be a good starting point:

`^.+\/truma\.aspx\?lang=en(&project=(31|32|33))?(&utm_source=.+)?(&.+=.+)*[^=|\?]$`

Step by step:

`^` The valid string starts after this character

`.+\/` This is valid for any amount of any mix of characters (at least one), followed by a `/`

`truma\.aspx\?lang=en` This is valid for `truma.aspx?lang=en` only

`(&project=(31|32|33))?` This is valid if there is the text `&project=31` where `31` can also be replaced by `32` and `33` it's also valid if the whole text does not exist

`(&utm_source=.+)?` This is valid for `&utm_source=` followed by any mix of characters. It is not mandatory. One could therefore think about removing it, as you want to allow any kind of arguments hereafter.

`(&.+=.+)*` as many arguments on top which start with a `&` followed by at least one character followed by a `=`. This whole phrase can be repeated as often as you like

`[^=|\?]$` the text is not allowed to end with `=` or `?`

You can test here for example:
https://regex101.com/

Comment: thanks,
but something is missing here.
in case the project is something else (for example 40) - it shouldn't be activated. only for 31/32/33 or none at all.

In addition, as this intended for Google Analytics - need it to start with the slash /